# Is Elasticsearch implementation in Liferay opensource?

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay

I am planning to integrate elastic search in my Liferay project. I searched a lots and found the [elasticray plugin](https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/41044606). but [elasticsearch's official website](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/pricing) discloses some pricing policy

Do we have to pay for elasticray?

Comment: Which version of Liferay are you running?

Comment: @Val I am using liferay 6.1

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing several things in your question and the comment to this question:

- Elasticray is a plugin that makes Liferay 6.1 and 6.2 talk to an Elasticsearch server. According to the marketplace link in the question it's free (and a click on "license" reveals that it's AGPL licensed) - so here's the answer if you have to pay for elasticray: No
- Elasticsearch is licensed under the [Apache 2](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) license. You don't need to pay for it
- Your price link goes to "Elasticsearch as a service". For this *service* you'll have to pay. You'll also have to pay if you need/want support for Elasticsearch.
- While software might be free, you'll need to run it on some hardware. You can expect the hardware to cost some money. If your application demands a highly powered machine, that might be pricy.
- If you have a high hardware demand, chances are that your business depends on the software being available and bugs being fixed quickly - and that's precisely why you would want to consider paying for OpenSource software despite being able to download it for free: You'll get support on an agreed on service level this way.

And, by the way, you have the same options for Liferay: Liferay CE is free (as in speech and beer), LGPL licensed. If you need/want support, you can get it through Liferay EE, which you'll have to pay for. And there are even companies offering Liferay as a service, for a fee.

Not to forget (Thanks to @Val) I was so much in the mood for answering in the scope of Liferay 6.2 that I forgot mentioning the fact that Elasticsearch is integrated in Liferay 7 and Liferay DXP. No more plugin required. And in this case as well you *can* get both fully supported on an agreed-on-service-level - on a paid contract. Or you can use them for free without any service or support. Your choice.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, it is worth mentioning that Liferay 7 integrates Elasticsearch as the default search engine, instead of Lucene in previous releases.

Comment: @olaf kock!! actually ES in production need some highly configure EC2 machine. when I checked machine price with same configuration its very heigh. so I am confused with all these things

Comment: Thanks @Val - I was so much in the mood of 6.2 that I forgot to mention this - I've added it now. And, Nitin Verma, I've edited my answer - now I'm totally unsure what you're looking for: Are you looking for the price of software or for the hardware that the software is running on?